$L^p-L^q$-estimates of heat semigroup
I am reading the book Superlinear Parabolic Problems by Pavol Quittner and Philippe Souplet, the proposition 48.4 :

Define
\begin{align*}
G_t(x)\,=\,(4\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\|x\|^2}{4t}},\ x\in\mathbb R^n,\ t>0.
\end{align*}
Let $\big(e^{-tA}\big)_{t\geq0}$ be the heat semigroup in $\mathbb R^n$
$$e^{-tA}\phi=G_t\ast\phi. $$
We have the following properties
(a) $\big\|G_t\big\|_1=1,\ \forall t>0$.
(b) If $\phi\geq0 $, then $e^{-At}\phi\geq0$ and $\big\|e^{-At}\phi \big\|_1=\|\phi\|_1$
(c) If $q\in[1,\infty]$, then  $\ \big\|e^{-At}\phi \big\|_q\leq\|\phi\|_q,\ \forall t>0$
(d) If $1\leq p < q \leq \infty $ and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q} $, we have
\begin{align*}
\ \big\|e^{-At}\phi \big\|_q\leq \big(4\pi t\big)^{-\frac{n}{2r}}\|\phi\|_p,\ \forall t>0.
\end{align*}
(e) For an arbitrary domain $\Omega \subset\mathbb R^n$, assertions (c) and (d) remain valid if $e^{-tA} $ is replaced with the Dirichlet heat semigroup in $\Omega$.

I get stuck with the proof of the proposition for (d) and (e) :

Interpolating between (b) and the inequality $\big\|e^{-At}\phi \big\|_\infty\leq\big(4\pi t\big)^{-\frac{n}{2} }\|\phi\|_1 $ we
obtain
\begin{align}
\big\|e^{-At}\phi \big\|_q\leq\big(4\pi t\big)^{-\frac{n}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{q} \right) }\|\phi\|_1.  \tag1\end{align}
Interpolating between (1) and (c) yields (d).
To prove assertion (e), denote by $e^{-tA_\Omega}$ the Dirichlet heat semigroup in $\Omega$. Let $\psi(x)=\phi(x)$ if $x\in\Omega$, $\psi(X)=0$ otherwise. We have
$$ \big|e^{-tA_\Omega}\phi\big| \leq e^{-tA_\Omega}|\phi| \leq e^{-tA}|\psi|. $$
The conclusion follows from assertions (c) and (d).

May anyone help me to clarify how to get the inequality (1) and how from there we obtain (d) ? And how from the final estimate we prove (e) ? Could someone give me some clarification for this ? Thanks a lot!
